# Rails 3.1 and minitest: How to test the "other" classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, minitest

For `controllers`, `helpers` and `models` are very good defined folders in the `test` folder.

But what about the classes in `lib`?

Where should we put this test?, in the epoch of the `test/unit` folder I liked to use this folder but now the folder is called `test/models` and now doesn't look like a good place.

I have created a `test/libs` folder but the `rake test` doesn't read from it :/

Also the tests created out of the *official* test folders doesn't inherit from the common `MiniTest::Rails::Spec` class and so I'm lossing the common *start* and *end* point to implement `DatabaseCleaner` strategies and this common things.

Comment: Hey @shingara - working on the same thing, how did you end up getting DatabaseCleaner to work?

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
require "./lib/class_name"
```

to load the file containing the class you want to test against

you can directly run this test file and skip all helpers to make it a instant-load test.